# When does the conversion happen when passing arguments to thread function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

When reading a book about c++ multi-thread programming, I came across one example below.

```
    void f(int i,std::string const& s);
    void oops(int some_param)
    {
       char buffer[1024];
       sprintf(buffer, "%i",some_param);
       std::thread t(f,3,buffer);
       t.detach();
    }
```

> In this case, it’s the pointer to the local variable buffer that’s passed through to the new thread, and **there’s a significant chance that the function oops will exit before the buffer has been converted to a std::string on the new thread, thus leading to undefined behavior.**

I know that it is the char* type argument buffer, not std::string is copied into the internal storage of thread t. What confuses me is that there's a chance the conversion from char* to std::string has not taken place even when thread t is already constructed. So when will the conversion take place? Is it just before the thread is scheduled to execute by the OS?

Comment: `t` holds `3` and `buffer` when begin constructed. But the invocation of `f` can occur after exiting `oops`.

Comment: @김선달 So the conversion takes place just when f gets its invocation?

Comment: Short answer: the conversion happens before the constructor of `t` returns. You're right that any other behavior could be disastrous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying the array argument is decayed to a `char*`, which is then copied for the thread. To be more specific the newly created thread executes basically the following expression:

```
std::invoke(auto(std::forward<F>(f)), auto(std::forward<Args>(args))...)
```

where `f` and `args` are the parameters of the `std::thread` constructor and `auto(/*...*/)` is the new C++23 syntax which creates a prvalue of the decayed type of the argument from the argument (and materializes a temporary object from it when being bound to the reference in the parameter of `std::invoke`).

However, in this evaluation the materialization of the temporary objects `auto(/*...*/)` is performed in the context of the caller of the thread constructor and the beginning of the call to `std::invoke` synchronizes with the completion of the `std::thread` constructor.

That means the `auto(/*...*)` decayed argument copies are made before the thread starts execution, but everything else happens as part of the new thread of execution.

So `auto(buffer)` will give a temporary object of type `char*` which lives until the end of the thread function invocation (because temporary objects live until the end of the full expression in which they are created). Then `std::invoke` is called with a reference to this temporary object as argument. This invocation happens in the newly created thread of execution and everything from here happens unsynchronized with the rest of the execution in the original thread.

`std::invoke` basically calls the copied `f` given to it as first argument and forwards the other arguments to `f`. Now since your `f` expects a `std::string const&` as second parameter, but `std::invoke` will pass it a `char*` as argument, a temporary `std::string` will be materialized, initialized from the `char*`, for the reference to bind to. This construction happens therefore in the context of the `std::invoke` call, which is already unsynchronized with the potential destruction, in the main thread, of the array to which the pointer points.